# Jira Filter for multiple Columns

Tags: filter, jira, jira-agile

I have my project called ”Service Del” in Jira, Every thing worked fine before when project was not getting bigger and bigger. But now i want some special type of filters.

I can use filter

```
project = "Service Del" ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

and can see all entries.

I can use filter

```
project = "Service Del" AND resolutiondate >= -7d ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

and can see all resolved entries from last week.

Till now every thing is fine.
As you can see in picture, I have 3 columns for this project, 
[image]
“To Do”, “in Progress” and “Done”. Now what I want is, I can filter this project in a way that, I can see all project issues in “To Do” and “In progress” columns **but in “Done” column it should display resolved issue only from last week.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
project = "Service Del" and (status in ("To Do","In Progress") or (status in ("Done") and resolutiondate >= -7d)) ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

please try to change the status names into the ones in each column, and use it as the filter.